# Local Push Notification : Can it be trigger by certain action? iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, push-notification, swift, appdelegate

I just found out below code for AppDelegate file, this will enable a popup that user needs to agree with push notification as soon as they open the app for the first time.

Can these codes be located in other viewController so that a certain action(such as a button clicking) trigger the popup? What I'd like to do is to located this "agreeing" process somewhere later on the process.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil))

    return true
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just invoke the registerUserNotification.. on any view controller you want.

Comment: Great. Can you let me know some example? I don't think AppDelegate.application is global, so not sure how to call this method on other viewcontroller.

Comment: You can get the instance pointer with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].